# How to schedule cron jobs in app engine?

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, cron

I want to schedule my cron jobs as like

```
every 5 minutes from 6 am to 1 am and every 30 minutes from 1 am to 6 am
```

How to schedule this in cron.xml within `<schedule tag>` and how to configure the time for `<timezone>` India?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say things like

```
<schedule>every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00</schedule>
```

inside the schedule tags. If you want to have "and" then I think create multiple cron entries.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Likewise you can configure the timezone:

```
<timezone>India</timezone>
```

What the specific value should be you'll have to find here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zoneinfo_time_zones

The timezone should be the name of a standard zoneinfo time zone name, as detailed on that page.

For example, for multiple timed jobs, from the docs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/recache</url>
    <description>Repopulate the cache every 2 minutes</description>
    <schedule>every 2 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
  <cron>
    <url>/weeklyreport</url>
    <description>Mail out a weekly report</description>
    <schedule>every monday 08:30</schedule>
    <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
  </cron>
  <cron>
    <url>/weeklyreport</url>
    <description>Mail out a weekly report</description>
    <schedule>every monday 08:30</schedule>
    <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
    <target>version-2</target>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Comment: i want to combine every 5 minutes from 6:00 to 23:00 and every 30 minutes from 23:00 to 6:00

Comment: Thanks for answering my question about GAE cronjobs before I even asked it :)

Answer (score 0):

For India, you need to use `Asia/Kolkata` timezone, and for combining both schedules you need to create 2 cron jobs.

It will be exactly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/your-endpoint</url>
    <description>Your task every 5 minutes</description>
    <schedule>every 5 minutes from 06:00 to 01:00</schedule>
    <timezone>Asia/Kolkata</timezone>
  </cron>
  <cron>
    <url>/your-endpoint</url>
    <description>Your task every 30 minutes</description>
    <schedule>every 30 minutes from 01:00 to 06:00</schedule>
    <timezone>Asia/Kolkata</timezone>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```